# Update the value of parameterizedCron from the Jenkins Declarative Script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline, build-triggers

I want to change the value in the Schedule box in Build periodically with parameters in a Jenkins job (see the image) using script in a declarative script while keep everything else the same.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cHr4.png)

Here is what I did:

```
properties([
        pipelineTriggers([parameterizedCron("H/15 * * * * % VERSION=1.2.3; ENV=prod")])
])
```

While it successfully change the value that I want but it also remove all other values in Build Trigger (see image)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYo6n.png)

How can I change the value of Build periodically with parameters while keep everything else's setting.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess, but I think you created the job and set the triggers in the job's config in the Jenkins UI.
Then you added the `properties` block in the Jenkinsfile.
This will overwrite the job config on next execution, so the solution is to add the missing triggers to the `properties` block in Jenkinsfile.

Jenkins has a build in help go to a PipelineJob and in the left manu ther should be a "Pipeline Syntax" item

[image]

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do but I got stuck on how to get the values of all existing triggers. Any idea?

Comment: Jenkins has a buildin help thing.
Go to a pipeline Job, in the left menu there should be a "Pipeline Syntax" link.
There you can select the "Declarative Directive Generator" and configure your triggers as in the Job config, but it will give you the code for the pipeline.